# Making an android app for a website

Tags: java, android, jsoup, forum

I'm trying to make an app for website that I DO NOT OWN OR HAVE ACCESS TO ITS DB.

The website is a forum community website and I wish make an app that can list the menu and the posts in a UI suited for mobile.

Also I am trying to see if I add real time notice function that will let the thread poster know when there is a new comment/post to his or her thread. (Website does not support this function)

Do you guys think I can achieve this through Jsoup or would I need other utilities too?
Also I am quite a beginner in java so the app cannot be too complicated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you want to write your own web browser! You need to call the Url get what it returns, parse it and show it... also you need to implement RSS to specific pages.. It means app need to call this url regularly and check if any changes or comments... Its do-able but wont really be efficient or bug-free... I wouldnt recommend it but as i sad do-able

Comment: Could you expand a little more on the part where I would need to use RSS?

Comment: You check the website regularly... always save the last session and compare the current website with the old one and see if there is any difference which is interesting to you... but as i sad parsin the web information can be really tricky